# React issue with backdrop, rendering not correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the file I wan to use the backdrop

```
import Aux from '../../hoc/Auxs';
import './Layout.css'
import Backdrop from './components/Backdrop/Backdrop'

const Layout = (props) => {
 const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
 const showSidedrawer = () =>{
   const newShow = !show
   setShow(newShow)
  }
  const toolbar = (<div className='Toolbar'>
                        <button className='Menu' onClick={showSidedrawer}><img src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/ffffff/menu.png"/></button>
                        <div>LOGO</div>
                        <div className='MenuMin'><ul>
                          <li>Burger Builder</li>
                          <li>Order Checkout</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>)
  const sidedrawer = (<div className='Sidedrawer'>
                        <ul>
                          <li>Burger Builder</li>
                          <li>Order Checkout</li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>)
                      // const backdrop = <div className='backdrop'></div>;
  return (
    <Aux>
        <div>
        {toolbar}
        {show && sidedrawer}
        {show && <Backdrop />}
        </div>
        <main>
        {props.children}
        </main>
    </Aux>
  )
}

export default Layout;
```

component

```
import React from 'react';
import './Backdrop.css';


const backdrop = <div className='backdrop'></div>;

export default backdrop;
```

CSS of component

```
.backdrop{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 400;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

when I kept the backdrop insire of the main file it was rendering correctly but when I put it in a separate file now I see just a white screen and the root div in react doesn't show any component. I tried checking on google but couldn't find much. Does anyone has any reason why it doesn't render correctly if moved to another file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue with making the component a function

```
import React from 'react';
import './Backdrop.css';


const backdrop = () =>{return<div className='backdrop'></div>;}

export default backdrop;
```